# Softphone icons not appearing after entering the credentials

Tags: cti

I am entering the credentials in the soft phone layout in sidebar . However the softphone icons are not appearing. Any specific settings that needs to be done??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're not able to see the buttons (you're referring to it as icons) - specifically those as shown below

[image]

There are a few things that may be at play here

1) The first thing to check is your user profile. Please see [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cti_admin_phonelayoutscreate.htm&language=en_US) link on how you can create a new Softphone layout or modify an existing one (this looks likely to be the issue)

2) By default the [following buttons are enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cti.meta/cti/cti_2_dev_custccedition.htm),

> Answer (BUTTON_ANSWER)
>
> Reject (BUTTON_REJECT)
>
> Release (BUTTON_RELEASE)
>
> Hold (BUTTON_HOLD)
>
> Retrieve (BUTTON_RETRIEVE)
>
> Transfer (BUTTON_TRANSFER)
>
> Accept Transfer (BUTTON_ACCEPT_TRANSFER)
>
> Complete Transfer (BUTTON_COMPLETE_TRANSFER)
>
> Conference (BUTTON_CONFERENCE)
>
> Accept Conference (BUTTON_ACCEPT_CONFERENCE)
>
> Complete Conference (BUTTON_COMPLETE_CONFERENCE)

If this is a standard setup, this should not be an issue. However, double check the `OnButtonEnablementChange` event in `CCTIUserInterface` to ensure these are present.